# How do I wrap asyncio calls in general-purpose non-async functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-3.6

I'm accessing a DBus API using `dbus_next`.  Since that's an asyncio library and the rest of my code is synchronous/threaded code, I wrap it up in a synchronous function:

```
intfc = "..."
path = "..."

async def dbus_call_async():
    bus = await dbus_next.aio.MessageBus(bus_type=dbus_next.BusType.SYSTEM).connect()
    introspection = await bus.introspect(intfc, path)
    obj = bus.get_proxy_object(intfc, path, introspection)
    return await obj.call_my_api()

def dbus_call():
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(dbus_call_async())
```

Note that Python 3.6 is a requirement.

This works - until it gets called in an asyncio context, when it dies with `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`.

Now, the obvious answer is to call the async version from async contexts and the sync version from sync contexts.  But of course there are numerous layers of function call between the asyncio context I'm now using it from and the wrapper function so this would mean maintaining parallel async and sync versions of **all my code**.  Which is plainly bonkers.

So what's the right way to do this?  How can I write a wrapper function that can be called from both async and sync contexts?

**Edit**  Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
import asyncio
import sys

async def async_call():
    return "Hello, world"

def _run_asyncio(coro):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(coro)
    return result

def wrapped_call():
    return _run_asyncio(async_call())

async def async_main():
    print(wrapped_call())   

def sync_main():
    print(wrapped_call())

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print("Calling in asyncio context")
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(async_main())
else:
    print("Calling in sync context")
    sync_main()
```

The important point here is that `wrapped_call()` should be callable from both sync and async contexts.  But the above only works when invoked without parameters, going via the sync route.  When invoked with a parameter, and so invoking `wrapped_call()` via `async_main()`, it produces the following stack trace:

```
Calling in asyncio context
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tkcook/test2.py", line 23, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(async_main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/tkcook/test2.py", line 16, in async_main
    print(wrapped_call())   
  File "/home/tkcook/test2.py", line 13, in wrapped_call
    return _run_asyncio(async_call())
  File "/home/tkcook/test2.py", line 9, in _run_asyncio
    result = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(coro)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 625, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 584, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. asyncio loop blocks when calling a non-async function. So you cannot use the same loop inside the blocking function. You may be able to create a new event loop and run in it

Comment: It's unclear and unspecific. Post a [mre] including code which represent all of your desired event loops. Anyway, in your example, you need to maintain only the ```dbus_call_async()```. Then why is it maintaining both parallel async and sync versions?

Comment: @relent95 I'll post a full minimal example in a minute.  The problem is that `dbus_call()` is only callable from sync contexts.  Now suppose that `dbus_call()` is a the bottom of some large library of code and I want to call that library code from an async context.  It dies horribly.  There is, AFAICT, no way to make this library work from both sync and async contexts.

Comment: @relent95 Minimal example posted.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the architecture of the asyncio. You should do like ```await async_call()``` in the ```async_main()```. So there's no point to devise a single wrapper function. Of course, it's also impossible.

Comment: Also, I recommend to use the ```asyncio.run()``` instead of the deprecated ```asyncio.get_event_loop()```.

Comment: This may be an XY problem. You need to provide an example of code which shows a maintenance problem and needs a refactor.

Comment: @relent95 I did specify Python 3.6 as a requirement - no `asyncio.run()`.  Yes, obviously in the stupidly simple case above the right thing is for `async_main()` to `await async_call()`.  But in practice the two are separated by a very large body of non-asyncio code.  At the bottom of that body of code, someone has decided to use an asyncio DBus library and at the top of the body of code I'm trying to use an asyncio web services framework.  There seems to be no way to make them work together without rewriting the entire body of code in-between (which then has a flow-on effect to other code).

Answer (score -2):

What you really should do is to keep a thread with an asyncio loop and submit your async calls to that thread with `loop.call_soon_threadsafe` or `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` - if you need these to take place in a concurrent way, from different threads, you'd have to keep a thread-pool with each thread running an asyncio loop.

If your async calls take place all from the same thread, however, and you just want to know if you are *already* inside an event loop, one way to check it is to call `asyncio.get_running_loop()`  (it will raise if you are not currently in an event loop).

However, if you *are* in an async context, there is no way you can *await* for the task to complete from a non-async function: you can fire your target co-routine as a task, and have whoever needs the result to "await" for it: your function should return the result directly, or a task - depending on how it is called, and it would be up to the callee, in an async context, to await for the returned task:

```
def _run_asyncio(coro):
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    except RuntimeError:  # not currently inside an event loop
        result = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(coro)
    else:
        result = loop.create_task(coro)
    return result
```

Comment: Answering an unclear question like this is not helpful to others.

Comment: I hope you noticed the question has been edited agree being commented as "unclear", and there is now a minimal reproducible example in code

Comment: As I commented to the question, the OP wrote code so it calls the ```wrapped_call()``` in the ```async_main()```. There's no point to do like that. It should be like ```await async_call()```. This implies he is misunderstanding the asyncio framework and asking an XY problem. So we need an example of code which shows a maintenance problem and needs a refactor.

Comment: And in your code example, what's the point of just returning a task without the corresponding ```await``` statement or an equivalent?

Comment: I ended up somewhere near this.  The code at the bottom of the pile creates a new asyncio loop and launches it in a new thread to run the task, using `Thread.join()` to wait until the task has completed.  It seems bonkers, and it violates asyncio rules in the case of an asyncio caller because it blocks in asyncio code, and the case where an exception is thrown etc is hard to handle, but it seems this is the sort of design choice the asyncio team have made.  Adopting asyncio little-by-little appears to be painful by design.